# Image not filling in table

Tags: html, css

Hi i have a table im trying to create to display products but am having trouble getting the image to display at its proper size any help would be appreciated.

```css
#tbldesktops {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#tbldesktops tr :nth-child(3) {
  width: 60%;
}

#tbldesktops tr :nth-child(1) {
  width: 15%;
}

#tbldesktops,
td {
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #fde981;
  font-size: 12pt;
  height: 8vh;
}

#tbldesktops th {
  color: #fde981;
  background-color: #4f41dc;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.productimg {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table id="tbldesktops">
  <tr>
    <th class="pctype" colspan="3">Desktop Computers</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img class="productimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg" alt="product name"></td>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Description</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

no matter what i have tried either setting the width or height manually it wont display it properly. here is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/w5rvdzk1/1/

Comment: I'd recommend not to use ids for CSS selectors. They are a PITA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your CSS

```
#tbldesktops tr :nth-child(1) {
  width: 15%;
}
```

selects the `<img>` in the table, as it is in fact the first-child of the `<td>`
and since it has higher specificity than `.productimg` the rules to this elector are in effect.

Change it to

```
#tbldesktops tr > :nth-child(1) {
  width: 15%;
}
```

to make it work

```css
#tbldesktops {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

#tbldesktops tr > :nth-child(3) {
  width: 60%;
}

#tbldesktops tr > :nth-child(1) {
  width: 15%;
}

#tbldesktops,
td {
  text-align: left;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  background-color: #fde981;
  font-size: 12pt;
  height: 8vh;
}

#tbldesktops th {
  color: #fde981;
  background-color: #4f41dc;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

.productimg {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<table id="tbldesktops">
  <tr>
    <th class="pctype" colspan="3">Desktop Computers</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Image</th>
    <th>Model</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td><img class="productimg" src="https://via.placeholder.com/200.jpg" alt="product name"></td>
    <td>Product</td>
    <td>Description</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thank you very much that makes more sense then it did before will try to remember this for future use